# Redirect A Live Website Visitor Without Them Refreshing or Clicking anything?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, redirect, visitors

I am hoping someone in the community can either tell me I am off my rocker, or that this is possible.

> The objective example; Someone is presently on a webpage, viewing the
>   content and/or watching a video. Let's say it's index.php, but we want
>   them to be on view.php. We click or save the php code and the page
>   automatically moves the visitor.

Presently, we can do this within WebinarJam, our live webinars (google hangouts) we just click a button inside the app hosting in the hangout and it redirects all the webinar attendees to another page, via opening a tab.

**Is it possible to do this while someone is on your webpage ?** I have search around and can't figure out if it is, or if I am just search for the wrong keywords.

Assuming you could create a "listener" to check every few seconds, I would think it would be possibles. Again, I am not an amazing coder like most who are within this community.

Appreciate the comments and information.

Comment: perhaps if you explained its purpose

Comment: I explained it above in the quotes section, but I am think you're looking for a reason. To which doesn't matter, but mostly if we see the user is on the wrong page and support wants them on a different page. It has to be possible, as I've seen it before but can't find the page I seen before.

Comment: well if that's your attitude, i'll go back to my paid job

Comment: I didn't have an attitude - might be the translation or something. What made you think I had an attitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would do it with using jquery like this...

```
<script>
var stuff="{'webnair':'1'}";
var move = 0;
$('body').on('click',function(){
    if(move){
     $.post('add.php',{stuff: stuff},function(data,status){
         if(status=='success'){alert('Done');}
     });
    }
});
```

Comment: So, how would be force the change ? just as state on save ?

Comment: actually this is just a sample, in actual application you need to have a system kind on a switch case for every state